# Is it right 'up' your alley or right 'down' your alley?

Tags: idioms

What is the more appropriate term for this idiom, up or down?

> Right ____ your alley.

According to [this idiom site](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/alley), either are in use, but I would like to get the opinion of this erudite crowd.

Does the answer depend on the slope of the alley?

Comment: I would always use 'up', same for 'right up my street'.

Comment: Either is correct, "up" is more common in the US, "down" is usually reserved for "my alley" vs "your alley" (normally without "right", as in "That kind of problem is sort of down my alley.").

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking about the "slope of the alley." There isn't actually an alley, of course; it's an idiom. Are you talking about when the phrase is applied to a domain of expertise/interest that has literal alleys? ("the bowling tournament was right up my alley", "mugging people was right up his alley") That case seems small enough that there is no established rule about it.

Comment: @apsillers I suppose I'm getting at the origin of the idiom.  When coined did the author envision an alley that does downhill, uphill or something else entirely.  Does one always go up an alley or down an alley?

Comment: The answer to your question is "up" as can be trivially found from any reference.  if you have another question ("how did this originate" . whatever), ask it.

Comment: I joined this site because I was researching this idiom, specifically the difference between "up" and "down". Here the difference is only relevant for AmE, because alley is essentially not used in the UK. So what is the reason for the user to use down, vs up? Why the change? I do not think it is regional, as in coke vs pop, nor cultural, but this is the question I am posing. I would also like your opinion on my own hypothesis. I think that" Down his alley" is an example of "physical" connotation. Possibly "up" is a positive or encouraging phrase to use, whereas "down" implies a negative or sar

Comment: BTW, why do you think it's a bowling alley?  Did you look up the definition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Google Ngram showing "right up your alley" is currently seven times more popular]

While *down your alley* appears to have been somewhat popular in the 1930s and 1940s, its usage has dropped considerably, and *up your alley* is vastly more popular in modern usage (by about a factor of seven). However, both phrases have seen recent usage, according to the samples linked [at the bottom of the Ngram page](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=right+up+your+alley%2Cright+down+your+alley&year_start=1800&year_end=2014&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cright%20up%20your%20alley%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cright%20down%20your%20alley%3B%2Cc0).

Anecdotally (as a native Mideast U.S. speaker, born well after the 1940s), I cannot recall ever hearing *down your alley* used idiomatically, but I am very familiar with *up your alley* as an idiom.

Comment: Try "down my alley".

Answer (score 4):

This usage nearly always features ***up***, not ***down***. The AmE version is usually ***alley***...

[image]

...but the BrE version is usually ***street***...

[image]

The meaning is the same in all cases *- something is exactly what you're **interested** or **skilled** in*. It's irrelevant to ask about "the slope of the alley", since it's a figurative usage anyway (no "real" alley or street is being referenced).

Answer (score 0):

The only version I've ever used personally, is: "Right up my alley," although if someone were to say it "Right down my alley," I would know what they meant, but it does sound a little odd; another saying which is very close in meaning to this one, is: "That's just what the doctor ordered," suggesting that the subject being discussed, is something which would be approved by one's physician, (metaphorically, of course).

Comment: I don't know that they are very similar in meaning.  To be "up someone's alley" means that it is in their area of expertise.  To say something is "just what the doctor ordered" means that it is the proper solution to your problem.  They really can't be used in the same situations at all.

Comment: Hey Jim, Correct. However, the meanings are, as I indicated, similar, not the same.

Comment: No. Not similar at all.  If you can use one in any given situation, the other does not fit.  Period.  It is misleading at best to offer these in the same answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was watching a British film circa 1930's and the phrase " right down your street" was said. I think an American take on that phrase " right up your alley" originated.